# Rubric Generator's adjustment

Tags: php, sql, html-table

I have create a table/ rubric for marking with 12 rows but what if the users fill in or use less than what is given? 
So what changes do I need to do to my php code to allow it since my code required user to input all 12 rows?

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("abc") or die(mysql_error());


$tablename = $_POST['title'];
$cat1 = $_POST['title_1'];
$cat2 = $_POST['title_2'];
$cat3 = $_POST['title_3'];
$cat4 = $_POST['title_4'];
$cat5 = $_POST['title_5'];
$cat6 = $_POST['title_6'];
$cat7 = $_POST['title_7'];
$cat8 = $_POST['title_8'];
$cat9 = $_POST['title_9'];
$cat10 = $_POST['title_10'];
$cat11 = $_POST['title_11'];
$cat12 = $_POST['title_12'];
$mark1 = $_POST['title_1_1'];
$mark2 = $_POST['title_1_2'];
$mark3 = $_POST['title_1_3'];
$mark4 = $_POST['title_1_4'];
$mark5 = $_POST['title_1_5'];
$mark6 = $_POST['title_1_6'];
$mark7 = $_POST['title_1_7'];
$mark8 = $_POST['title_1_8'];
$mark9 = $_POST['title_1_9'];
$mark10 = $_POST['title_1_10'];
$mark11 = $_POST['title_1_11'];
$mark12 = $_POST['title_1_12'];

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $tablename (
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
$cat1 INT($mark1), $cat2 INT($mark2), $cat3 INT($mark3), $cat4 INT($mark4), $cat5 INT($mark5), $cat6 INT($mark6),
$cat7 INT($mark7), $cat8 INT($mark8), $cat9 INT($mark9), $cat10 INT($mark10), $cat11 INT($mark11), $cat12 INT($mark12),
Total INT (200))")
 or die(mysql_error());  


header("Location: index2.php");

?>
```

Here is the interface:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rubric</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="rubric.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="formWrap"> 
    <center>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Rubruc's Title:<h2>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title" >
            </td>
        </tr>
       </table>

       <table>     
        <tr>
            <td>
            Please input text before numbers (Example: TPR2211).
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

      </br>
        <table border = "1" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign = "center" align = "center" bgcolor = "#fffff7">
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            Category
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#fffff7">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>

                    <td valign = "center" align = "center" bgcolor = "#fffff7">
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            Max. Marks
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#fffff7">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>

                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_1" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                        <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_1" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_2" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                    Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_2" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_3" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_3" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_4" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_4" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_5" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_5" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_6" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_6" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_7" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_7" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_8" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_8" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_9" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_9" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_10" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_10" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_11" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_11" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign = "top" width = "200">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_small">
                            <table border = 0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign = "top">
                                        <div id = "div_small">

                                        Input your category:<br>
                                        <br>
    <input name = "title_12" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
         size = 20 maxlength = 100 class="textPage">
                                        <br> <br>
                                        Add your max. marks in the rubric text boxes to the right:<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>                   

                    <td valign = "top">
                        <br>
                        <div id = "div_content_bold">
                            <br> <br>
                            <input name = "title_1_12" type = "text" value = "" class = "input"
                              size = 20 maxlength = 200 class="textPage">
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor = "#C2C2C2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>

            <div align = "center">
                <table border = "0" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "0" width = "300" bgcolor = "#ffffff">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign = "center" width = "3000"><button type="submit" style="background-color:transparent; border-color:transparent;"> 
                        <img src="submit.png" width = "130" height = "60""/></button>
                        </td>

                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                        <td valign = "center" width = "400"
                            ><a href = "javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you wish to cancel your changes?')) {document.location=document.location;}"                         
                                ><img width = "80" height = "70" src = "reload.png" border = "0" alt = "Reload Page" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td align = "left" valign = "center">
                            <div id = "div_small_bold">
                                Submit and Preview 
                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                        <td align = "center" valign = "center">
                            <div id = "div_small_bold">
                                Clear and Reload
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

    </center>
    </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Short answer for the immediate issue: you need to set default values.

Comment: Longer hint about your code: there are a few basic issues here: 1. the old mysql database adapter has been deprecated long go, you really should use the current variants `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. 2. your code is wide open to sql injections, every client can execute arbitrary sql statements and even shell commands on your system with that code. 3. Dynamically creating tables at runtime is a questionable strategy. 4. Using dynamic column names at runtime is questionable too. However with that little information you provide, we cannot say much more than these general things.

Comment: arkascha I am still learning the basic and not sure on how to use msqli or PDO. Another thing is I want to enable the users to add the values as I said above this will be use in a marking sheet.

Comment: The modern database adaptors `mysqli` and `PDO` are documented just like the old one. You _did_ read into the documentation, didn't you? ;-) If not, start _now_: http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php Not really more difficult, but you can write more secure code with that. Though it does not make your code more secure all by itself. Take a look at the examples for `mysqli` here on SO.

Comment: About the dynamic creation of tables: I do not see why you should want to create new tables for each such "sheet". Why not one table for all columns in all sheets and one table holding the "meta data" of the sheets? That would be the "normal" approach and prevent dynamic creation of tables and columns which certainly will create issue for you in future.

Comment: I see...but I am required to allow multiple creation of marking sheet with different limit of marks like 1st one with Report with INT (20) as max mark is 20 while the second is only 15 after that, I will need to generate a graph of max mark of all students as one table will represent a whole class as one rubric will be use to mark 20-40 students. (This is a assignment project so, I just need it to function as describe)

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow in all details here. Could you explain that a bit? What do you mean by "Report with INT (20) as max mark is 20"? What is "max mark"? Are you really aware of what `INT(20)` means? Why is generating a graph relevant for how you plan to store the data? What exactly do you mean by "rubric"?

Comment: I am using INT (20) also as the limit of marks that can be input in the table (The table will later  be generate into a marking sheet). The generating of graph is by class so, if one table have multiple class it will generate all of it at once that is what make me split the table by class (One class will have one table in database). Rubric is the marking sheet that will generate by using the table

Comment: Why can't you simply filter that table by a class parameter when generating the graph? That would be how relation databases are usually used. It is the idea behind it.

Comment: Could you show me an example? I am still learn so, it will help a lot